# Problem with a JS function not returning any result

Tags: javascript, function

I'm quite new at JS and I can't figure out why this is not working :

```
  function printEvens (someArr) {
   for (let i = 0; i < someArr.length; i ++) {
     if (someArr.length % 2 === 0) {
     console.log(someArr[i]); 
     } else if (someArr.length % 2 !== 0) {
     continue;
     }
   }
  };

printEvens ( ['Amsterdam',
  'Barcelona',
  'Berlin',
  'Lisbon',
  'Madrid',
  'Mexico City',
  'Miami',
  'Paris',
  'Sao Paulo'] );
```

(I'm trying to get only the even results)

Do you have any clue ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You need to take the modulo of `i` not of `someArr.length`. The latter won't change.

Answer (score 0):

From your function name, I assume that you are trying to print all even items from the array.
In your loop, instead of checking whether the position/index (here `i`) is even, you were checking the length of the array.

```
someArr.length % 2 === 0 // wrong
```

Try the following (didn't test it though)

```
function printEvens(someArr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < someArr.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      console.log(someArr[i]);
    } 
  }
}
```

You also don't need the `else` part.I know you are new to SO. Please try to add more details to your question.
Good luck

Comment: Thank you, it worked and the "else if" part I added was also unnecessary then !

Answer (score 0):

I just want to log them (sorry for the misusage of "return", quite new in this). I want to log only the results with an even index.

I found another solution by writing :

```
    function printEvens (someArr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < someArr.length; i += 2) {
    console.log(someArr[i]); }
   }
```

But I'm doing this as an exercise and I was supposed to use %

Answer (score -1):

This is a lot different than your old thing, but this should work:

```
function printEvens(someArr) {
    for (i = 0; i < someArr.length; i += 2) {
        if (someArr[i]) {
            console.log(someArr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of checking if the value is even, we just skip ahead with the addition assignment operator `+=` to instantly reach the next even value.